# Where can I learn about the lattice of partitions?

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

A set $P \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a partition of $X$ if and only if all of the following conditions hold:

1. $\emptyset \notin P$
2. For all $x,y \in P$, if $x \neq y$ then $x \cap y = \emptyset$.
3. $\bigcup P = X$

I have read many times that the partitions of a set form a lattice, but never really considered the idea in great detail. Where can I learn the major results about such lattices? An article recommendation would be nice.

I'm also interested in the generalization where condition 3 is disregarded.

Comment: the generalization you are referring to is sometimes called the "lattice of subpartitions"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

G. Birkhoff, Lattice Theory. Providence, Rhode Island, 1967,

[Chapt.4, sec.9](http://books.google.com/books?id=0Y8d-MdtVwkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 6):

George Grätzers book *General Lattice Theory* has a section IV.4 on partition lattices,
see page 250 of [this result of Google books search](http://books.google.sk/books?id=SoGLVCPuOz0C&lpg=PP1&dq=general%20lattice%20theory&pg=PA250#v=onepage&q=partition%20lattices&f=false). A more recent version of the book is called *Lattice Theory: Foundation*.

Answer (score 4):

[The Logic of Partitions: Introduction to the Dual of the Logic of Subsets](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CFkQFjAE&url=http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/8966/1/Logic-of-partitions5.pdf&ei=bDczUtu8F-mZiAeWvoHYCQ&usg=AFQjCNHonb9jj9hC9Zdm0J5uEtxm4qIcug&sig2=0HxfuFG3_8cb7KPGHXjrhg&bvm=bv.52164340,d.aGc)

I just stumbled upon it a couple of days ago, but it looks to be a great reference.