# Book for partitions and equivalence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

#### I couldn't find a similar question on the site; if it exists I will delete this

Our teacher is covering a lot of theory and theorems about equivalence classes, partitions and basics of those. Now he is doing semi-groups and monoids. All the standard abstract Algebra books don’t cover this in detail. I would like to know some references.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408539/where-can-i-learn-about-the-lattice-of-partitions). Not a duplicate though.

Comment: Well I remember Artin had a section on partitions and equivalence classes.